# Correct shadows for the Xamarin frame ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, shadow

I made a custom render shadow for the frame element - everything is fine the shadow that turns out to suit me, but because of using this custom render I get a bad effect on the RadioButton element, how do I edit this render so that the radio button element is normal?
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rptWf.png)

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Renderer to update all frames with better shadows matching material design standards
    /// </summary>

    public class MaterialFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);

            // Update shadow to match better material design standards of elevation
            Layer.ShadowRadius = Element.CornerRadius;
            Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;
            Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(2, 2);
            Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.40f;
            Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
            Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something goes wrong with RadioButton Rendering , we even can't create custom renderer for RadioButton on iOS ,check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/430069#Comment_430069 .

I strongly recommend you  to use [Xamarin.Forms.InputKit](https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit#radiobuton) instead of Xamarin RadioButton .

It is pretty nice.

```
xmlns:input="clr-namespace:Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls;assembly=Plugin.InputKit"

  <Frame  Margin="100" CornerRadius="20"  >

            <input:RadioButtonGroupView>
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 1" />
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 2" />
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 3" />
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 4" />
            </input:RadioButtonGroupView>
        </Frame>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]